# How to dynamic load html file and execute the exernal js in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html file:index.html which contains some basic js libs.
And I also have some modules：

a.html:

```
<div id='a'>
  <script src="a1.js"></script>
  <script src="a2.js"></script>
</div>
```

a1.js:

```
console.log('a1')
```

a2.js:

```
console.log('a2')
```

How can I dynamically load a.html into index.html and get the event that a1.js and a2.js are completed executed?

Comment: Review this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35615845/2813224), if it helps upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

use `w3data.js` to do that ( [w3data.js](http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js) )

***Example:*** in index.html

```
<html>
<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>

<body>

<div w3-include-html="a.html"></div> 

<script>
w3IncludeHTML();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but, how can I get the event that a1.js and a2.js are completed executed?

Comment: as this includes your a.html file, so this will also execute your a1.js and a2.js file

Comment: I read the source code of w3data.js and found it use innerHTML to append the external html file: a.html. I know that it will load a1.js and a2.js and execute them, but I want to catch the event that  a1.js and a2.js are executed immediately. Is possible to do that ?

Comment: To catch the event of  a1 you have to write some code before or after console.log('a1') in  a1.js. same in a2.js

Comment: I got an idea that I can use AJAX to get a.html`s content, use regex to get all <script> tag. Then I remove all this <script> tags and append the remain contents to index.html.Finally I use AJAX to load js files which are in <script> tags,and after execute them, I manually trigger 'all_js_loaded' event. But I am a beginner in js, and not sure that does it make sense or are there better methods.

Comment: that sounds so complex

Comment: Yes, it is. Because I want to achieve that I can dynamic load a.html/b.html which include some external js file and get the event that all external js file are executed. And people who write a.html/b.html have no need to append any code to a.js/b.js, they just need to write a normal html file and a normal js file.